# Prestashop 1.7 - Get Database parameters

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

**Situation:** I need to get the parameters of the database from one PrestaShop 1.7, i know that are in parameters.php but i dont know how to get it in another .php. 
The code of parameters.php are the following.
How i get the parameters??
Thanks.

```
  <?php return array (
  'parameters' => 
  array (
    'database_host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'database_port' => '',
    'database_name' => '',
    'database_user' => '',
    'database_password' => '',
    'database_prefix' => 'ps_',
    'database_engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'mailer_transport' => 'smtp',
    'mailer_host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'mailer_user' => NULL,
    'mailer_password' => NULL,
    'secret' => 'fIz1vXGf14HQP0gYIGSOv3yqWAswhTLQ6JRAvCnAytNUUJgVOoHWYhip',
    'ps_caching' => 'CacheMemcache',
    'ps_cache_enable' => false,
    'ps_creation_date' => '2017-10-09',
    'locale' => 'es-ES',
    'cookie_key' => '457GbAM3q5ctnvb0wjyyVcuNO0SfzFFxZghNSKW2TWhc9GfzPSvKDAQc',
    'cookie_iv' => 'RvcXmr9J',
    'new_cookie_key' => 'def00000ce15b57d4b2e1cdb214464708c3fefc4145607fff1400890a08aa234e5b5c7b0061a1af4647cbdf668ad9f383739c95f710f0e3d606d0e07dc11c20e42d6f0ec',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$config = require _PS_CACHE_DIR_ . 'appParameters.php';
var_dump($config['parameters']['database_host']);
```